# What are the the characteristics of a standing wave?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

[image]

May someone explain #24 from this picture? B is apparently the correct answer. Can any of the other answers be correct here? Isn't D also correct?

Comment: For D, hint: sound wave is a longitudinal wave

Comment: What about C though?

Comment: For C, see animations at right [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave#Opposing_waves)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is incorrect because a node, rather than an antinode, would exist at the reflection surface.

C is incorrect as the oscillations would be out of phase.

D is incorrect because sound is generally a longitudinal wave, although I would say the diagram is confusing on this point.

Comment: One shouldn't give the full answer for homework questions

Comment: sorry, I'm kinda new to this, should I delete the answer

Comment: Well, I think it's a bit too late, the answer is accepted, and the OP can't unsee it :)

Comment: ok, sorry, I'll be more careful in future